# Autoheight for table with \si units

Tags: tables, preamble

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}         %Einheiten mit Bruchstrich 
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            Eingabeparameter & \textbf{Einheit im Programm} \\
            \hline
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\  
            \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The Newton and the Metre do not have enough space on the top and on the bottom. What could I put in the preamble that sets the height of table row higher if there is a si unit that takes more space? The entire table should have higher rows then, not only that one with high si unit. Also tables without the need of more space should not use more space.

Comment: Suggestion, drop the vertical lines (no-one uses vertical lines anymore), then replace the three `\hline` with \toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` from `booktabs`. They have much better spacings than `\hline` but does not support vertical lines.

Comment: I'd much prefer the slashed form in that context.

Comment: I think we're missing the point here. It's got nothing to do with the table (which indeed should be done with booktabs). It's just about the vertical spacing in an `\si` application.

Comment: Erm no. I was wrong.

Comment: The vertical spacing is not optional. Nobody wants to read negativ exponents in units. booktabs runs smooth. I just forgot about it since my last thesis, it was still in my preamble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}         %Einheiten mit Bruchstrich 
\usepackage{booktabs}               %Ermöglicht bessere Linien in Tabellen 
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \toprule
            Eingabeparameter & \textbf{Einheit im Programm} \\
            \midrule
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\
            \midrule
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\  
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note you can move the `\sisetup{per-mode=fraction} ` into the table environment if you only want that formatting for this table.

Comment: Please also note that `booktabs` horizontal lines are incompatibel with vertical lines.

Comment: @leandriis Did I use horizontal lines in this solution?

Comment: With "`booktabs` horizontal lines" I referred to `\toprule`, `\midrule`  and `\bottmrule` which are all present in your answer. Take a closer look at the intersections between these horizontal lines and the vertical lines you added with `|`. There will be small white gaps around the intersections.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `cellspace` package. In the following example, I have also replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` command as the first one adds some additional white space.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{per-mode=fraction}         %Einheiten mit Bruchstrich 
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
    \begin{document}    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|Cl|Cl|}
                \hline
                Eingabeparameter & \textbf{Einheit im Programm} \\
                \hline
                Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\  
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Here are three additional versions using the `booktabs` package. (Personally, I'd prefer the second or last of them):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}         %Einheiten mit Bruchstrich 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}  


\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ClCl}
            \toprule
            Eingabeparameter & Einheit im Programm \\
            \midrule
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\ 
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\ 
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\  
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal} 
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule
            Eingabeparameter & Einheit im Programm \\
            \midrule
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\ 
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\ 
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\  
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol} 
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \toprule
            Eingabeparameter & Einheit im Programm \\
            \midrule
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\ 
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\ 
            Symb:vFzg       & \si{\newton\per\square\metre}     \\  
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question by solving the problem the preamble. But on the other side, daleif has it right, that I should use \toprule  \midrule \bottom rule. I had even the package \usepackage{booktabs} already in my preabmle. I just forgot about it since the last Thesis I wrote.